# Flex on SM but not on XS

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="d-sm-flex flex-sm-row flex-sm-row-reverse">
   <div class='ml-2'></div>
   <div class='ml-2'></div>
   <div class='ml-2'></div>
</div>
```

Which works as intended, howeer in XS mode I want to display columns as usual.  But if I set the div classes to `col ml-2` then it ruins the flex display. How can I set this to display cols in XS but flex in SM and above?

Comment: Hi, I see you added the bootstrap4 tag, so I assume you are using it? So, for `xs` to `sm` you want normal columns and for `sm` and up you want it to be flexed?

Comment: @Corné that is correct

Answer (score 0):

So based on your comment here is what you can do:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
     <div class='col-4 col-sm-12 ml-2'>TEST</div>
     <div class='col-4 col-sm-12 ml-2'>TEST</div>
     <div class='col-4 col-sm-12 ml-2'>TEST</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I made use of Bootstrap's `row` and `col` and placed it all in a `container`. But the concept for the columns is that for sizes up and to `sm` it will be `col-4` (you can change the column sizes to your desire) and for everything after `sm` it will be `col-12` meaning it will fill the width.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer but please read my post again.  I want to retan the flex-display for anything SM and above, and col for XS.  If I add `col` to the divs with `ml-2` in them the flex display is ruined.

Comment: Okay I might be understanding what you want. What if you add a size to the `col`. Because just using `col` will fill the excess space. So make it `col-1`?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="d-flex flex-row-reverse">
   <div class='col ml-2'>11</div>
   <div class='col ml-2'>22</div>
   <div class='col ml-2'>33</div>
</div>
<div class=" d-flex  flex-row-reverse">
   <div class='ml-2'>44</div>
   <div class='ml-2'>55</div>
   <div class='ml-2'>66</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```